# Marklogic 6 , Calling Resource Extension in java

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I need to upload and use a xquery module to **marklogic 6** like check-docAvailable.xqy. I tried using the dictionary.xqy sample given by ML6, it works well. But when I try to import my own xquery I'm getting below error.

```
ERROR :
Exception in thread "main" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: config/resources write failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: XDMP-IMPORTMOD: Cannot import Main Module /marklogic.rest.resource/dictionary/lib/resource.xqy.  See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putPostValueImpl(JerseyServices.java:2033)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putValue(JerseyServices.java:1918)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceExtensionsImpl.writeServices(ResourceExtensionsImpl.java:114)
    at com.mobius.ln.ml.util.MLUtil$DictionaryManager.installResourceExtensionShortcut(MLUtil.java:279)
    at com.mobius.ln.ml.util.MLUtil.main(MLUtil.java:202)
```

My Xquery Module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare variable $uri as xs:string external;

let $uri := $uri
return (
fn:doc-available($uri)
)
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this. Is there any mistake in Xquery?

Comment: "See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail." -- did you do this?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a read through [Extending the REST API](https://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/guide/rest-dev/extensions).  Your XQuery module doesn't look like a REST extension.  When I attempt to install your module via curl

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -i \
  -H "Content-type: application/xquery" \
  --data-binary @/c/temp/a.xqy \
  -X PUT http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/resources/a
```

I get the following error:

{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":400, "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT", "message":"RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid a extension: could not parse XQuery extension a; please see the server error log for detail XDMP-IMPORTMOD: Cannot import Main Module /marklogic.rest.resource/a/assets/resource.xqy; a either is not a valid module or does not provide extension functions (delete, get, put, post) in the http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/a namespace"}}

Comment: Thanks sam, i will rewrite my xquery and check.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the error message looks significant:

> XDMP-IMPORTMOD: Cannot import Main Module /marklogic.rest.resource/dictionary/lib/resource.xqy.

That looks like you deployed dictionary.xqy as a service extension, using the REST API, then tried to import that module into another. dictionary.xqy is apparently a main module, but only library modules can be imported. See [XQuery Library Modules and Main Modules](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_45509) in the Application Developer's Guide for more info about that.

I think what's happening is that you're deploying a main module as a service extension, but such extensions are required to be library modules. Take a look at [Guidelines for Writing XQuery Resource Service Extensions](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_41710) in the REST Application Developer's Guide, taking note of the [Resource Extension Interface section](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_75991).

Solution: rewrite your extension as a library module, using the required interface.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will rewrite my xquery and check